EPPlus returning different values ​in the same version
I have an API in .NET Framework that receives a list of cells to populate and returns the result of a specific cell after performing calculations. I'm currently migrating this API to .NET 8. To achieve this, I created a new API and implemented it in the same way as the original .NET Framework version. However, I'm encountering an issue where some results are not matching as expected. For example:
.NET Framework API: "Value k13: 387.856496---Value L1:1.7---"
.NET 8 API: "Value k13: Commission: 387.8564960000001---Value L1:1.7---"
The formula used in the target cell is: "CONCATENATE(K9,L9,\"---\",K8,L8,\"---\")"

The problem occurs when concatenating decimal values from cells. In the .NET 8 version, the decimal values are returned with extra precision (more decimal places), whereas I need the output to match exactly what is returned by the .NET Framework API.
Both APIs are using EPPlus version 4.5.2.1.
Note: Initially, I suspected this might be a culture-related issue, but I’ve ensured that the culture settings are identical in both APIs.
Any suggestions on how to force the new API to be the same as the old API? There are many different spreadsheets that hit this API, I needed to make the return identical to the old API.

Can you just cast to float to get rid of the extra precision before concatenating?

It's not me who does the concatenation, I just throw it to EPPlus and some clients use concatenated cells, I just return the cell to them, this behavior only occurs in the concatenated cell, when I try to bring the separate cells, in both APIs the same result is returned, the problem is in the return of the concatenation
